# tool for extracting xpath query from speciifed/selected node

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

Normally, one would use an XPath query to obtain a certain value or node. In my case, I'm doing some web-scraping with google spreadsheets, using the `importXML` function to update automatically some values. Two examples are given below:

```
=importxml("http://www.creditagricoledtvm.com.br/";"(//td[@class='xl7825385'])[9]")
=importxml("http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/ELIPCAM:BZ";"(//span)[32]")
```

The problem is that the pages I'm scraping will change every now and then and I understand very little about XML/XPath, so it takes a lot of trial and error to get to a node. I was wondering if there is any tool I could use to point to an element (either in the page or in its code) that would provide an appropriate query.

For example, in the second case, I've noticed the info I wanted was in a span node (hence `(//span)`), so I printed all of them in a spreadsheet and used the line count to find the `[32]` index. This takes long to load, so it's pretty inconvenient. Also, I don't even remember how I've figured the `//td[@class='xl7825385']` query. Thus why I'm wondering if there is more practical method of pointing to page elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some clues :

- Learning XPath basics is still useful. W3Schools is a good starting point.
  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp
- Otherwise, built-in dev tools of your browser can help you to generate absolute XPath. Select an element, right-click on it then >Copy>Copy XPath.
  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open
- Browser extensions like Chropath can generate absolute or relative XPath for you.
  https://autonomiq.io/chropath/

Comment: W3Schools is my go-to reference, but I never got the gist of XPath from there. Still the best reference I've ever found. Your second bullet is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. Chropath seems great if I wasn't using Chrome already.